# Create HMAC SHA1 in C using pure linux crypto api

Tags: c, linux, hmac, cryptoapi

I need to apply HMAC SHA1 on some scatterlists in a C program.
I have a sample code written for **kernel 2.4** hmac crypto api, that uses this function:

`void crypto_hmac(struct crypto_tfm *tfm, u8 *key, unsigned int *keylen, struct scatterlist *sg, unsigned int nsg, u8 *out)`

but the crypto API in **kernel 3.13** and after is SO MUCH DIFFERENT than 2.4!

I looked everywhere to find any example of using new strange minimalized function

```
static int hmac_create(struct crypto_template *tmpl, struct rtattr **tb)
```

provided in **hmac.c (source/crypto)**, but I cannot find any topic or examples that uses kernel crypto api **specificly** **hmac** transform.

Any body has any experience using **Linux Crypto API HMAC in C**? Using this procedure will not be more than a few line of C codes.

Comment: Hi there did you solve this? On Windows and Mac there are built in APIs for crypto which handle hmac_sha1, I was now trying to do same on *nix.